# How to inject content to Twig generated content?

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to inject content to Twig generated content after everything else has been parsed and done.

Right now I'm using this code below:

```
public function onResponse(KernelEvent $event)
{
    // TODO: find a better way to inject
    $event->getResponse()->setContent(
        $this->asseticProcessor->inject($event->getResponse()->getContent()));

}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        KernelEvents::RESPONSE => array('onResponse', -9999),
    );
}
```

However, I feel like it may not be the optimal way to do so. First of all, at least I want to do the injection only when Twig HTML templates are actually rendered (in some cases, the controller can simply return a response without rendering anything, or they can render json and in such case I don't have to manipulate the content)

Comment: could you add some more details to your question pleae? what exactly are you trying to achieve? what do you mean by `inject content to twig` ?

Comment: hi nifr, I need to modify the very final content of the request response (after all the parsing etc through various twig functions, filters). So I need to catch that final response string, and modify it before the response object is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but you could use a kernel event listener for this.  For example:

```
services:
    response_modifier:
        class: Some\Bundle\Listener\ModifyResponseListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse, priority: -127 }
```

Set the priority very low so that it fires towards the of the response chain.  The listener might work like so:

```
class ModifyResponseListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // We probably want to ignore sub-requests
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $content = $response->getContent();
        $content = preg_replace('/foo/is', 'bar', $content);
        $response->setContent($content);
    }
}
```

The above will replace all occurrences of "foo" with "bar" in the final output.

Note that you might also have to check that the response is not a redirection, ajax, stream or whatever before modifying the content.